Ubuntu 22.04 LTS error: `Failed to import pool 'rpool'. Manually import the pool and exit.`
I have Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on my Dell XPS13 laptop. I have not used the laptop for a while. Recently, I started it up, but received an error:
Gave up waiting for suspend/resume device Aborted

Command: /sbin/zpool import -c /etc/zfs/zpool.cache -N 'rpool'

Message: cannot import 'rpool': no such pool or dataset nvpair_value_nvlist (nvp, &rv) == 0 (0x16 == 0) ASSERT at ../../module/nvpair/fnvpair.c:586:fnvpair_value_nvlist() Error: 134

Failed to import pool 'rpool'.

Manually import the pool and exit.

I consulted chatgpt on how to fix this; it's answer is here: https://gist.github.com/mtthsdzwn/57396466cd5fb92a9dc868070c98a839 (a bit long, so posting as a gist). The advice seems sensible, and I followed along up to Point 3, zpool import -a, with no result. I am far from an expert, and would like to check first with this community if I should continue. Should I follow the advice?
